# Using pymongo filter data find v.s where

Tags: mongodb, find, pymongo, where-clause

I want to filter data using pymongo. But I don't know how is this two methods different. The Result show first method's performance is better than second. But I already filter a query set list in my storage. Is this mongodb feature? or pymongo feature?

This Following is my example cases:

1. Use find method:(faster)

   ```
   result = pymongo.db.mycollection.find({
      condition1,
      condition2
   })
   ```
2. Use find method & where expressions:(slower)

   ```
   query_data = pymongo.db.mycollection.find({
      condition1
   })

   result = query_data.where(Code("function() {
     return condition2}"))
   ```

**In official documentation, mentions that if can use standard operators avoiding use $where expression.[Doc.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically given the answer already yourself. The first version should be your preferred option as the second one using `$where` will result in slower execution times. One of the reasons for that is e.g. that `$where` will not use any indexes ([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations)).

You can see the queries that the PHP driver really sends to MongoDB in the server logs by enabling logging on the server like this:

[db.setLogLevel(1)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/)

Also, once you know the precise queries you can use [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to compare the different execution plans.